# Удалить все элементы содержание класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начал изучать чистый javascript. Представим проверку формы, где ошибки выводится под каждым тегом `input` элементом `<span class="error"></span>`. Необходимо удалить все элементы с классом `error` в блоке с формой.
На jQuery функция бы выглядела так: `$('.error').remove();`. Собственно вопрос, как реализовать это на чистом javascript?
Пробовал так и не совсем правильно отрабатывает функционал:

```
while(element.length) {
   element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
}
```

Написал функцию, которая не отрабатывает :)

```
function removeElement(elementClass) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    delete (element);
}
```

Comment: начните с того, что по имени класса возвращается коллекция, а не один элемент. это намек на цикл, если что

Comment: Спасибо. Про коллеции вообще не было понимания :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(element.length) {
  element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
}
```

Этот код работает конкретно в связке с `getElementsByClassName` - он возвращает "живой" список элементов, который будет обновляться после каждой операции. Так, начинается цикл: Удаляется первый`[0]` (в JS счет начинается с нуля) элемент из списка. Заново собирается весь список, снова удаляется первый элемент, и так по кругу.

А было бы приятно один раз собрать все элементы, по очереди всё удалить, и всё. Поэтому в большинстве случаев вместо getElements... используют `querySelectorAll('.класс')` - он один раз ищет элементы и возвращает статичный список. Предыдущий код не сработает для него, т.к. `element.length` не будет обновляться после каждого круга.

А вариантов удаления много:

```
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.className'); // обращаю внимание на точку

// Вариант адын
for( let i = 0; i < test.length; i++ ){
  test[i].outerHTML = "";
}

// Вариант два (forEach - метод массивов, но встроен еще в querySelectorAll)
test.forEach(function(elem){
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
});

// Варииант три (в JS тоже есть remove(), IE его не поддерживает)
test.forEach( e => e.remove() );

// Разные циклы использованы для разнообразия. Всё можно сделать через классический цикл.
```

Answer (score 1):

Это правильный код:

```
  while (element.length) {
    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
  }
```

Что у Вас "и не совсем правильно отрабатывает"?

```js
function removeElement(elementClass) {
  let element = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  while (element.length) {
    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeElement('error')">Remove</button>

<span class="error">*</span>
<span class="error">*</span>
<span class="error">*</span>
<span class="error">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elems = document.querySelectorAll('.error');
for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i]);
}
```